# Pythai on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

Dose anyone have experience installing pythai on mac OS.
I get the following error when I try and install it with "pip install pythai"

```
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/roopal/anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/roopal/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c pythai/libthai.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pythai/libthai.o
    pythai/libthai.c:3:10: fatal error: 'thai/thbrk.h' file not found
    #include <thai/thbrk.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Not sure where to get and put the thai/thbrk.h file

Answer (score 2):

If you Google `pythai`, the first result that comes up is the project's [Github page](https://github.com/hermanschaaf/pythai). If you click on it, then scroll down to the readme, it says in the Installation section

> PyThai requires `libthai-dev` to work.

and gives installation instructions for Debian/Ubuntu. Since you're on OS X, you'll need to build the source from scratch. Going back to Google, a search for `libthai` leads you to the [LibThai website](https://linux.thai.net/projects/libthai/). Reading that page, you'll find that the code is hosted on [Github](https://github.com/tlwg/libthai). Click on Releases and download the `tar.gz` of the latest version, 0.1.25. Unpack the archive, enter its base folder, and run `./autogen.sh`. If you get an error about an undefined macro, do what it says and rerun `autogen.sh` with the `m4_pattern_allow` argument. Once that completes, do the usual for building a package from source - run `./configure --help` to see if there are any particular options you want to set, then run `./configure` plus any desired flags, then run `make`, then run `sudo make install` and you should be all set.

Obviously, this requires you to have XCode and the XCode command-line tools installed and activated.

Comment: Well, that's a lot of steps... Why not run in a Debian docker container? :)

Comment: @cricket_007 that's what you do when you build a library from scratch. You generally don't need the `autogen.sh` part, as `configure` is usually built beforehand, but in this case it wasn't. It actually isn't *that* much work...